# How do I widen the white box with CSS on this website?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, size, vs-web-site-project

The website is http://bio.shinobiarts.net/BIO/
I've found through trial and error that the function

`div.entry-content {
  width: 1000px;
}`

will make the white box smaller, but I can't make it any bigger.

I'm very new with CSS so any advice/tips are appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The div has a `max-width` set to it. Remove it with this CSS rule:

```
.page > .entry-content,
.page > .entry-header
{
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

**EDIT**: Added `.page`, because the rule wasn't taking effect
**EDIT2**: Added the rule for `.entry-header`

Comment: Thank you, but the white box will still not increase in size.

Comment: Ah, the rule's being overruled. Here, let me edit my answer.

Comment: Thank you! I accepted the answer because it did indeed enable the white box to be expanded. However, it is no longer a uniform square, but is now not as wide at the top of the box. I suspect it has something to do with "h1"? Again, you answered my initial question, thanks!

Comment: You're welcome. I edited my answer again. Now the header should become wider, too.

Comment: Wow. I figured out how, but that's way less code than I had, much cleaner. I appreciate it!